# Variable does not exist: RecordTypeId

Tags: apex, record-type

I have record types in Asset object in my target org. In the test class which am trying to deploy to target org, i have referred recordtypeid.

Iam trying to deploy the test class via ANT but on validation, am getting "Variable does not exist: RecordTypeId" error. Am not sure if this is an intermittent issue in SF? Below is the code i have written in test class.

```
Id assetRtId = Schema.SObjectType.Asset.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Number Block').getRecordTypeId();
Asset assetObj = new Asset();
assetObj.Name = 'Asset_0';
assetObj.AccountId = ProdBsktAcc.Id;
assetObj.LG_TelephonyProductConfiguration__c = prodconfvoiceprod.id;
assetObj.LG_PortInOperator__c = 'BT';
assetObj.LG_SoftDeleted__c = false;
assetObj.RecordTypeId = assetRtId;
assetObj.LG_NumberRangeType__c = 'Port-In';
insert assetObj;
```

Comment: Make sure you're deploying to the correct org. You should only get this error if there are no record types in the org.

Comment: Don't use ANT. If you're going sandbox to sandbox you can paste in your code and verify if the error persists. If so, it has nothing to do with deployment. If it does not error and you can confirm it is ANT issue, use a change set. Also, Provide the FULL error (stack trace) as that will help us help you pinpoint the issue. Also, try a minimal code snippet. Create a class that does almost nothing but reference the field and try to deploy to see if issue persists. To me, it seems like you haven't done enough troubleshooting. (or update your answer to show you've already done these).

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved, i have amended the API version of the test class (in meta file) to 38.0 (near latest version). The test class was a old one and it was set to 27.0 earlier!